# Setting JAVA_HOME for Hadoop on Mac

Tags: macos, hadoop

I have problem setting up JAVA_HOME correctly for Hadoop on OS X 10.7
Here is what I have done:
went to /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.0.3/libexec/conf/hadoop-env.sh and changed JAVA_HOME form whatever it was there for default to **export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home/**
I am also pretty new to Java too, so even JAVA_HOME might be wrong too . 
So by going to bin folder of hadoop and running this command: **hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar**
This is the nasty error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job jar: hadoop-*-examples.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:90)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:88)
```

Do you have any idea how can I fix this or what is the problem?
this is also the output of "which javac" commnad in case you need it:  **/usr/bin/javac**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must have gone to the "libexec" folder and then ran that command.

Answer (score 3):

Hadoop example jar file is hadoop-1.0.3-examples.jar` for the version of Hadoop which you are using. Use the proper jar file name in the command and it should work.

Coming to the JAVA_HOME, it's set proper since you are getting a Java exception, otherwise  it would have been a different error.

Hope it helps. For those who are getting started with Hadoop, here is a [consolidated](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/p/hadoopresources.html) list of useful resources.

Comment: but when I used wild card in the command, adoop-*-examples, shouldn't it work regardless of version number?

Comment: I think Hadoop looks for the exact file name.

Comment: Check this [tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.3/single_node_setup.html). You should run it as `bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'`. Make sure the jar file is in the location where it is specified. The Hadoop framework is not able find the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Me also face the same issue, please check your jar file and class name, Java is case sensitive. also check with your command which should have a proper space in between each word

now i resolve the issue.. all the best

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question. Use *comments* for posts like this.